# Error trying to Plot data with different size using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to plot two variables for several years. The first variable is measured every hour, and the second is measured every 24 hours. But both correspond to the same period. I'm using the following code:

```
x1= np.arange(0,129392)
x2=np.arange(0,129392,24) 
fig_1,ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x1,Data_OBS_h,'k',marker='o',linestyle=' ',label='PM10-1h',linewidth=1.5)
ax1.plot(x2,Data_OBS,'r',linestyle='-',label='PM10-24h',linewidth=1.5)**
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=15)
fig_1.savefig(Titles[i]+'.png')
```

I've made a secondary axis with values like 0,24,48,..But I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension.
```

Someone know how to fix this? In addition, I need to use `plt.subplots()` to be able to change size of `tickmarks`.

Thank you very much,
All the best,
Sebastián.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make any sense. Each point in your line must be specified by both an x and a y coordinate. If you have different numbers of x and y coordinates then how can you know where to position each point in the line?

Comment: It would help if you showed us what the dimensions of `Data_OBS_h` and `Data_OBS` are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure this holds:

```
assert len(x1) == len(Data_OBS_h)
assert len(x2) == len(Data_OBS)
```

Then you should be able to plot what you want.